# Prove that $ \delta _{ik} \delta _{kj} = \delta _{ij} $

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-delta

This is a neat Kronecker-Delta Identity, but I don't know how to go about proving it. Intuitively, I understand that all non-zero contributions to this sum are when $ i = j = k $, but the answer that I saw was that if we say $ \delta _{kj} = A_{k} $, then we can simply write this as $ \delta _{ik} A_{k} = A_{i} = \delta _{ij} $. However, that substitution seems arbitrary - why $ A_{k} $ instead of $ A_{j} $ ?

Comment: It's the transitive property of equality. Is A=B and B=C then A=C.

Comment: $i$ and $j$ are fixed indices, while $k$ is dummy. So pretend like you are fixing $j$; and of course you can do the same with $i$, if you want.

Comment: Its the identity $II=I$.

Comment: Are these Kronecker delta's and are you assuming a summation convention, or is $\delta_{ij}$ the matrix with a 1 at $(i,j)$ and a 0 elsewhere? This expression would be vaiid in both cases.

Comment: If the Einstein's summation convention is not assumed, then it dose not hold, because $0=\delta_{12}\delta_{21} \neq \delta_{11}=1$. So, the identity is $\sum_k \delta_{ik}\delta_{kj} =\delta_{ij}$ or $\sum_k \delta^i_k\delta^k_j =\delta^i_j$.